# How to remove all tags in XML file to display only desired text

Tags: notepad++, xml, editing

What command would I use to remove all tags to display only what I want shown. There are hundreds of entries, only want to display the --name-- tag. Here is an example of a single entry.

Original Line

```
    <game id="149526">
    <path>./1943mii.zip</path>
    <name>1943: The Battle of Midway Mark II</name>
    <desc>1943: The Battle of Midway Mark II is an unofficial  US version of the 1943 kai.</desc>
    <image>./images/1943mii-image.png</image>
    <video>./videos/1943mii-video.mp4</video>
    <marquee>./images/1943mii-marquee.png</marquee>
    <thumbnail>./images/1943mii-thumb.png</thumbnail>
    <rating>0.5</rating>
    <releasedate>19870101T000000</releasedate>
    <developer>Capcom</developer>
    <publisher>Capcom</publisher>
    <genre>Shoot'em up / Vertical</genre>
    <arcadesystemname>capcom</arcadesystemname>
    <players>1-2</players>
    <md5>5152b779738392fe2d6471b8c11a8b10</md5>
    <lang>en</lang>
    <region>us</region>
    </game>
```

Line Needed

```
    1943: The Battle of Midway Mark II
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<game.+?<name>(.+?)</name>.+?</game>`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<game       # open tag
.+?         # 1 or more any character, not greedy
<name>      # tag
(.+?)       # group 1, 1 or more any character, not greedy
</name>     # close tag
.+?         # 1 or more any character, not greedy
</game>     # close tag
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      # content of group 1 (i.e. the name)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An XML-aware utility such as `xmlstarlet` is preferable over `grep` in most cases. There is no guarantee that the game element will be on it's own line.

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/game/name" -n file.xml
1943: The Battle of Midway Mark II
$
```